# Equality of line integrals when dot product is equal

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

The line integral over a vector field $F$ is defined as (from Wikipedia)

$$\int_C \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})\cdot\,d\mathbf{r} = \int_a^b \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t))\cdot\mathbf{r}'(t)\,dt \tag 1$$

notice that the expression on the left of the equality sign is just a notation for the line integral, its meaning is expressed by the integral on the right.

Then I came across the [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque#Relationship_between_torque,_power,_and_energy) of work in angular motion:

In physics, work is defined as

$\displaystyle W=\int _{s_{1}}^{s_{2}}{\vec {F}}\cdot \mathrm {d} {\vec {s}} \tag 2$

knowing that, $\displaystyle \mathrm {d} {\vec {s}}=\mathrm {d} {\vec {\theta }}\times {\vec {r}}$, we can make a substitution for $\mathrm {d} {\vec {s}}$ and obtain:

$\displaystyle W=\int _{s_{1}}^{s_{2}}{\vec {F}}\cdot \mathrm {d} {\vec {\theta }}\times {\vec {r}} \tag 3$

So far so good, in equation (3) the vector ${\vec {F}}$ hasn't changed and $\mathrm {d} {\vec {s}}$ has been replaced by an equal vector, so if we calculate it using the equation in definition (1), the value of the integral stays the same, because the derivative of ${\vec {\theta }}\times {\vec {r}}$ is equal.

Next, using the properties of triple product, we conclude that

$${\vec {F}}\cdot \mathrm {d} {\vec {\theta }}\times {\vec {r}}={\vec {r}}\times {\vec {F}}\cdot \mathrm {d} {\vec {\theta }} \tag 4$$

knowing that ${\displaystyle {\vec {\tau }}={\vec {r}}\times {\vec {F}}}$ we get:

${\displaystyle W=\int _{\theta _{1}}^{\theta _{2}}{\vec {\tau }}\cdot \mathrm {d} {\vec {\theta }}}\tag 5$

However it's not obvious to me why we're allowed to substitute (4) and (5) in equation (3).

To me, the fact that the dot products $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})\cdot\,d\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{s})\cdot\,d\mathbf{s}$ are equal doesn't imply the line integrals $\int_C \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})\cdot\,d\mathbf{r}$ and $\int_C \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{s})\cdot\,d\mathbf{s}$ are equal as well.

Could anyone explain that, provide a theorem or a proof of it?

Now after giving it a bit more thought, the only explanation I have is - just use the definition of the line integral and the definition of the function differential. Writing the definition of line integral as a limit of the sum, we get the result:

$$\int_a^b \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t))\cdot\mathbf{r}'(t)\,dt
$$ $${\displaystyle I\ =\ \lim _{\Delta t\rightarrow 0}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\mathbf {F} (\mathbf {r} (t_{i}))\cdot \mathbf {r} '(t_{i})\,\Delta t,} \tag 6$$

so from the definition of function differential 
$${\mathbf {r} '(t_{i})}\Delta t=\Delta\mathbf{r} \tag 7$$

Comment: the substitution seems ok to me, why do you think it's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This derivation is distinctly a physics derivation rather than a mathematical derivation, so you're right to be a bit skeptical. However, the derivation does work and can be made rigorous (the way this is derived is a common shorthand for the full method).

Here is one derivation (I'm omitting vector hats, so keep track of the what's a vector and what isn't):

$$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\tau(\theta)\cdot d\theta=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\tau(\theta(t))\cdot \theta'(t)\text{ } dt
=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}({r}(t)\times{F}(s(t))\cdot \theta'(t)\text{ } dt
$$
Then, by the scalar triple product formula:
$$=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}F(s(t))\cdot \theta'(t)\times r(t)\text{ } dt\\=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}F(s(t))\cdot s'(t)\text{ } dt\\
=\int_{s_1}^{s_2}F(s)\cdot ds\\=W.$$

The key in the mathematical derivation is that you have to keep track of what variable each vector is parameterized with respect to. Here I have chosen to parameterize $F$ in terms of $s$ (the position vector), while $r$ and $\theta$ are in terms of time $t$. This is because we want to eventually integrate the force over a displacement.

An extra comment: This derivation does not work in general, because $ds=d\theta \times r + dr \times \theta$ in general, and that second term is only zero for a rigid body rotating with respect to a fixed origin.

Comment: In the last equality with the integral sign, you have used the definition of function differential to convert from $dt$ to $ds$, right?

Comment: That's right, and I suppose I'm assuming there that the force is conservative. Or you could interpret the second to last line as a path/contour integral, assuming the $F$ isn't conservative. In that case, you just integrate over a path connecting $s_1$ to $s_2$.

Comment: So if the force is conservative, you can write $\int _{s_{1}}^{s_{2}}$, if not, you have to use $\int_C$, correct, because it depends on the path, not just on the endpoints $s_1$ and $s_2$? To clarify, I understand that $\int_{s_1}^{s_2}F(s)\cdot ds$ or $\int_{C}F(s)\cdot ds$ is only a symbol used to denote a line integral, the meaning of the symbol is given in the definition of the line integral (as I mentioned at the beginning of my question)? If so, the answer to my first comment should be no, you didn't use definition of differential, but the definition of line integral...

Comment: ... that gives $\int_{s_1}^{s_2}F(s)\cdot ds$ in this case.

Comment: My point is that the standard definite integral is defined as $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \sum_{x=a}^{b} f(x)\Delta x$. Does 

$\int_a^b f(x) \cdot dx$ denote an integral, with the only difference that we're taking a dot product, like this?  $\int_a^b f(x) \cdot dx = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \sum_{x=a}^{b} f(x) \cdot \Delta x$, or it should be treated as a line integral that is independent of the path, a mere symbol without an intrinstic meaning?

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand your question, but I believe it should be treated as a path integral, using the definition of the line integral you gave at the start of the post.

Comment: Ok, thanks, could you explain where you're assuming there that the force is conservative? Looking at your last comment, I don't think you are?

Comment: I mean this: $\int_{t_1}^{t_2}F(s(t))\cdot s'(t)dt
=\int_{s_1}^{s_2}F(s)\cdot ds$ is true by definition of the line integral, it actually is the definition of line integral, which is the expression on the RHS, so there is no assumption about path independence that could even be made at this point.

Comment: If you view the integral as an actual integral from $s_1$ to $s_2$, then the force has to be conservative for the equation in the definition to be true. If the force wasn't conservative, the integral would depend on the path taken between the endpoints, not just the endpoints. However, the integral $\int_{t_1}^{t_2}F(s(t))\cdot s'(t) dt$ is always well-defined and equal to the work, so if we view $\int_{s_1}^{s_2} F(s)\cdot ds$ as a formal symbol which doesn't actually denote anything except the time integral it's defined to be, then you're right it's true by definition.